# Standard I/O File Descriptors

Tags: shell, files, io-redirection

I code this

```
$ ls -l 1> stdout.txt
```

and I get the output as desired,

```
1> stdout.txt
```

redirects the output from standard output to the file stdout.txt.

I don't see any such file existing on disk. What kind of file system supports such files, is it **ramfs**?

Does this have any similarity to the **procfs** and **sysfs**?

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of filesystem is in use. If you use `1> stdout.txt` (or, more commonly, just `> stdout.txt`), you should get a file called `stdout.txt` in the current directory. If the file can't be opened in the current directory (permission problem or some other error), you should get an error message informing you of this.

Comment: my Question was,in what type of file system do we have stdout, stdin. they do have file descriptors, so they are files, right? i was expecting something on the lines of **procfs** and **sysfs** or some other kind of **psuedo fs**

Comment: stdin, stdout, and stderr are file *descriptors*, not files. They may refer to files (or pipes, or sockets, etc...). In this case you made the stdout file descriptor (which is 1) refer to your file `stdout.txt` in the current directory. It doesn't matter what type of filesystem `stdout.txt` lives on.

Comment: What “such file” are you refering to? The only file involved in that command is `stdout.txt`, which the command creates.

Comment: such file is the one with the file descriptor 1, i obviously know that the txt file is not inquestion, maybe i didn't put the question in the right way, but its fine. got the answer. its __procfs__, thanks to @sukminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Linux, and I read your question correctly, yes look in [`/proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

For a specific process look in `/proc/[pid]/fd`, e.g. `ls -l /proc/123/fd/`

There is also a special way to reach current process fd's by: `/proc/self/fd`.

Note that e.g. `ls -l /proc/self/fd` would be for the `ls` process and not for
your current shell, which you can see by:

```
cat /proc/self/cmdline | tr '\000' '\n'
```

or

```
cat /proc/self/status
```

For the last look especially at `PPid` which should be PID of your shell.

```
Name:   cat
State:  R (running)
Tgid:   12696
Pid:    12696
PPid:   312
```

---

As an experiment you could try to open two terminal windows:

1. In window 1 enter `echo $$` to get PID of that shell.
2. In window 2 say `cat /proc/[pid]/fd/1`
3. In window 1 start typing and observe what happens in window 2.

---

- [/proc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) at kernel.org
- [proc](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) at TLDP
- [Filesystems](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fs.5.html) at man7.org